# Does default mahout programs runs over hadoop in cluster

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I have 3 operations from Mahout and I want them to run over Multi-Node Hadoop cluster.

Does these operations could run?

```
seq2sparse, trainnb, testnb
```

I try to run it, but it seems that all executes over one machine(master).